# PHP get dynamically the namespace off a class by concating it

Tags: php

I have a string, route, and i explode it and then i have a classname. `$callback = explode('@', $callback); $callback[0]` is the classname. I am making a router and based on the class and methed i return this.

I want to get the full namespace and when i use this then it works but now i want to make it dynamically.

How do i concat BaseController to the ::class?

```
BasController::class

$fullclass = HERE I NEED THE FULL NAMESPACE$callback[0];
$class = new $fullclass;
$method = $callback[1];
$class->$method();
```

Exaple index.php

```
Router::route('/user/{id}/' , 'BaseController@show');
Router::execute($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Router:

```
namespace App;


class Router
{

private static $routes = array();

private function __construct()
{

}

private function __clone()
{
}

public static function route($pattern, $callback)
{
    $pattern = $pattern;
    self::$routes[$pattern] = $callback;
}

public static function execute($url)
{
    foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $callback) {
        if ($pattern == $url) {
            $callback = explode('@', $callback);



            $fullclass = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Controllers\\' . $callback[0];
            $class = new $fullclass;
            $method = $callback[1];
            $class->$method();
        }else{
            echo 404;
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i was looking for is giving the class as param into the route

```
Router::route('/user/{id}/' , App\Controllers\BaseController::class , 'show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to retrieve namespace

```
echo (new \ReflectionClass($object))->getNamespaceName() ;
```

If you are in that scope try

```
__NAMESAPCE__
```

See this document if you are looking for [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Doesn't work because i need the full namespace and that's the problem. At that point in my code it's not knowing. I only know the clss name BAseController. Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class BaseController does not exist in

Comment: can you post the code where you want to acheive this ? I'm little confused with your question.

Comment: I have a string, route, and i explode it and then i have a classname. $callback = explode('@', $callback); $callback[0] is the classname. I am making a router and based on the class and methed i return this. See my edit.

Comment: @Bas why are you making a router? there are hundreds of them readily available. Just use https://github.com/nikic/fastroute and be done with it.

Comment: I know @Gordon, but i want to make one self.

Comment: I think you are not getting right answer because question is not clear to us. I've many question, please do not reply in comment, update your post. please include more details in question. I've following question and more.. What $callback contains ? Which file you are current is ? Do you have a variable that contains string "BaseController" ? do you want to search find namespace ?

Comment: @Bas i think you are trying to autoload classes, see this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php. there are few steps to do. set_include_path, spl_autoload_register then spl_autoload and resolve your class. then call your method. there is a call_user_func_array method which you can use to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

BasController::class returns a full class name in string in that case you can simply concat any string on it. If $callback[0] is a string you can do below code.

```
$fullclass = BasController::class . $callback[0];
$class = new $fullclass;
$method = $callback[1];
$class->$method();
```

Comment: the word BaseController is variable, so i need a solution to concat BaseController or an other class name to ::class